# Wordpress sanitize hidden value

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a hidden field in `Wordpress`

```
<input name='af_field[]' class='temp_cls1' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $param[0] . ":" . $param[1] . ":" . $param[2]; ?>'/>
```

How can i sanitize and escape the hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the information given..

You deal with hidden fields exactly the same way as visible fields, the `$_POST` supervariable will contain the information.

so one way of doing this is:

```
 $hidden_var= sanitize_text_field($_POST[af_field][0]); // note you are passing a array of values so do a foreach if there are a few values.
```

then in your form:

```
<input name='af_field[]' class='temp_cls1' type='hidden' value='<?php echo esc_attr($param[0]) . ":" . esc_attr($param[1]) . ":" . esc_attr($param[2]); ?>'/>
```